# Problem with text mode in \substack

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, accents

I have defined a differential command in this way

```
\let\underdot\d
\renewcommand{\d}{\ifmmode\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\else\expandafter\underdot\fi}
```

so that I don't loose the text accent (I don't know how `expandafter` works, I put it there just after trial and error). But I have a problem, if I use `\d` as the first command in a substack, it gives me the *text* `\d`. Here is an example code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\let\underdot\d
\renewcommand{\d}{\ifmmode\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\else\expandafter\underdot\fi}

\begin{document}
\[
    \substack{\d x = \sigma \d y}
\]
\end{document}
```

I don't know why this happens, may be my command is bad defined, or may be there is a bug in `\substack` (`subarray`). I can solve it with `{}\!\d x = …` but I would like to fix it globally.

#### How can I fix that? Which is the best way to solve that (may be redefine the command `\d` in another way)?

Comment: A better definition of `\underdot` would be the (admittedly complicated) incantation `\expandafter\let\expandafter\underdot\csname\encodingdefault\string\d\endcsname`

Comment: @egreg I don't have any more problems, but I believe you, and I will substitute the line `\let\underdot\d` by the one you provided (if I haven't misunderstood you, this is what you say, isn't it?).

Comment: The simpler `\let\underdot\d` *might*, under some circumstances, lead to infinite loops, because the expansion of `\d` refers to `\d` itself. When you redefine `\d` in terms of `\underdot` you could fall into one of those (rare) circumstances.

Comment: The redefinition of `\d` is exactly the same as before; the `\expandafter` in it is for getting rid of `\fi`; in the complicated `\let` instruction it is for making `\csname` act before `\let` is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `\DeclareRobustCommand` or  put `\relax` at the start of your definition  otherwise an `\ifmmode` test at the start of any alignment cell will be false as it is expanded *before* the cell starts (and math mode is entered) while TeX is looking for `\omit` (`\multicolumn`)