# Renaming \d for differentials

Tags: math-mode, macros, best-practices

I know this question might sound dangerously like asking for an opinion, but I nevertheless give it a try. Since I never used the "underdot accent" `\d` I renamed it to get a differential in math mode

```
\renewcommand*{\d}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

Out of portability I decided to change it a little bit in order to preserve the original meaning in text mode, writing

```
\let\originald\d
\renewcommand*{\d}{\relax\ifmmode\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\else\d\fi}
```

This didn't work, for the underdot in text mode was horribly placed. Then I tried the following contruct (now in a MWE)

```
\documentclass{article}   

\let\originald\d
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\d}{\relax\ifmmode\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi\originald}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Compare \d{x} with $\d{x}$.
\end{document}
```

which seems to work properly.

My question is: could there still be some cases where this construct breaks down? Or maybe a better approach? Or is this simply a very bad idea which I shouln't use under any circumstances? ;-)

Comment: It's a bad idea. Bibliography items could have `\d`. And it's a bad idea, generally, to have a command perform very different things in math or text mode.

Comment: @egreg Coping with bibliographies was exactly the reason I wanted to "save" the text mode definition (even if I never had the problem). But of course you are right about the different behaviour. Unfortunately, too much old stuff relies on the math `\d` to simply throw it away :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some time ago I got this

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\letcs\originald{\encodingdefault\string\d}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\d
  {\ifmmode\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\else\expandafter\originald\fi}
```

and, without `\letcs`

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\originald\csname\encodingdefault\string\d\endcsname
\DeclareRobustCommand*\d
  {\ifmmode\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}\else\expandafter\originald\fi}
```

I don't know if it works or not, but I did not made that up :) May be it would be better to `\def` rather than `\let` the `\originald` macro?

Comment: Ok, my solution with two `\expandafter`s plus `\@gobble` and `\@firstofone` was way too complicated and unnecessary ;-) But what should be the advantage of your first line(s) over simply `\let`ting?

Comment: So long as you don't mix encodings in a document such definition may work. But there are several ways things can go wrong.

Comment: @campa The first code is more readable but the second doesn't need the `\letcs` command, it's your choice.

Comment: @Manuel I meant why not simply `\let\originald\d`, but egreg just answered that.

Comment: @egreg That's why I ask in the last line that may be it's better with `\def` rather than `\let` (which fixes the `\csname`). Even if it's not recommended `\d` as a differential, I think it would be nice to have an official complete answer just in case we want to be bad. If that answer is not this one I posted (or the same with `\def`) I would gladly upvote it if you write it.

Comment: @Manuel BTW, I have now found the older question of yours http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97557, so my question might be a duplicate. Unless someone else writes in the next few hours I will accept your answer.