# Can I renewcommand \d? What does it mean?

Tags: math-operators

I want to conveniently write `\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}` for differential operator and I prefer to use `\d` for this command. But `\d` is already defined. What is this command? Can I & Should I redefine it?

Comment: It makes and underdot accent. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262091/82917 for a possible workaround.

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. `texdef`says `{\o@lign {\relax #1\crcr \hidewidth \sh@ft {-1ex}.\hidewidth }}`. As @campa said, it puts a dot under the first argument.

Comment: You can define it under the  name `\dd` instead.

Comment: No, you should *not* redefine `\d`.